# How can I precompile assemblies?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET, and making a small update to a site that already exists. I am confused about the differences I see on the production server vs. the source code I've been given, and would appreciate any explanation or advice. Normally I would just continue reading and researching until I understood fully, but in this case I've been asked to make a small update to something ahead of my understanding. All I need to do is change one element in a form.

On the production site, there are files like `\contact\survey.aspx`; no `.cs` files exist in the directory alongside them, and there's no `CodeFile` directive. Instead, there are a multitude of DLL files corresponding to these pages, like `bin\App_Web_survey.aspx.fdf9difs9.dll`.

When I was given the source code of the site to edit, I see something different. The `bin` folder is entirely lacking in these DLL files corresponding to pages; instead, each `aspx` file has an `aspx.cs` file sitting next to it in its folder, a code-behind. Fair enough, I think; the site can run in its interpreted mode, like this, or compiled to DLLs.

Problem is, for the life of me I cannot work out how to do that; I've read dozens of pages on the MSDN library and gotten nowhere.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web, and I've opened the source code folder as a website. When I run 'build', it succeeds, but no DLLs are made, not even in the Debug folder. [This MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464(v=vs.100).aspx) has instructions for compiling *web application* projects, but the options don't correspond to the available options for me, so I'm guessing that either web application and web *site* are distinguished or that Visual Studio 2013 (which I also tried using and had no luck with) is distinguished from VS *for Web*. I'm at a loss.

**tldr**: Can anyone quickly sum up for me the process of compiling an ASP.NET website in a way that results in multiple DLL files in its `bin` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to use [`aspnet_compiler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229863.aspx):

`aspnet_compiler -p sourceCodeRoot -v / targetRoot`

See [***How to: Precompile ASP.NET Web Sites for Deployment***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227976.aspx) (*MSDN*).